# How do I use Intents with ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I know there are many solutions to solve this problem.

But it's not same case as that.

This is my java code.

```
package com.progme.sejong_bus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BUSActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bus);

        String []data =
            {"공통공지사항","101번 버스정보","102번 버스정보","103번 버스정보","104번 버스정보",
                "105번 버스정보","106번 버스정보","107번 버스정보","108번 버스정보","109번 버스정보",
                "110번 버스정보","111번 버스정보","112번 버스정보","113번 버스정보","114번 버스정보",
                "115번 버스정보","116번 버스정보","117번 버스정보"};

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and this is my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want intent to each list.. but how can i select each list?

And what code that i have to use?

**EDIT>**

I want to see my app is working like this image.

[image: SampleImage]

Each list is link for each page.

And I can't do this because i have no idea with code for to work like this.(?)

Anyway.. what I have to do??

Comment: So everytime you click on an item you want to go to a different `Activity` or?

Comment: no i mean I want to link list 1 by 1 XML.
but i don't know how i can coding this..

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you want.

Comment: I'm sorry.

I edit my post. please check it and answer to me..

Comment: you need to do the redirections with the comparison of your list view position.

Comment: I can't understand what are you saying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO first you need to use an array to get the list items where your current current 
string []data= in your main java code can be replaced with this

```
    // Listview Data
String[] List_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.List_items);
```

create a new xml file in values and paste this code iv just called the list Lise_items
just replace the (list item) with whatever you like in your list view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="List_items">
<item>list item </item>
<item>list item</item>
<item>list item</item>
<item>list item</item>
<item>list item</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

by added the onclick listener

```
/// listening to single list item on click

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          /// selected item 

          String List_items = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          /// Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item

          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          /// sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("List_items", List_items);
          startActivity(i);

      }
    });
}
```

}

You will need to create another xml file and java file for the view on click

for example

```
list_item_view.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/List_item"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>    
        </LinearLayout>

Listitemselected.java

        package com.progme.sejong_bus;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;


        public class Listitemselected extends Activity{
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.setContentView(R.layout.list_item_view);

                TextView txtList_items = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.List_items);

                Intent i = getIntent();

                // getting attached intent data

                String List_items = i.getStringExtra("List_items");

 // displaying selected List name
                txtList_items.setText(List_items);

            }
        }
```

You will have to create a new intent for each item that is in the list so when each item is clicked it will go to a new activity for example

```
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 

    Intent a;
     switch(position){

    case 1:
        a = new Intent("Items 1 page");
        break;
     case 2:
       a  = new Intent("items 2 page");
       break;

    if(null!=a)
    startActivity(a);
 }
```

}

Comment: And how i can select each list and make intent to it?

Comment: I hope this helps i re edited my post a good place to go as well is to search for tutorials on google. You might have to change some of the names to mach accordingly to your project

Comment: yeah didnt see the edited post as what i wrote will take you to a new page on a listitem clicks but need a new intent for each seperate click